# How to navigate JSON file, get desired object and push it into array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How to read JSON file and push it into array using javascript? I don't find any example as deep as this one. This JSON will goes on and on thru year. Thanks in advance.
*source taken from firebase.
*poor grammar is not a crime ^_^
*navigate and read JSON object. Sorry for the lack of knowledge.

```
{
"Year": {
    "2017": {
        "Jan": {
            "A": {
                "Actual Sales": "14",
                "Code": "3",
                "Comment": "15",
                "Date Due": "8",
                "Date Received": "7",
                "Description": "6",
                "Drawing Number": "4",
                "Due Day": "12",
                "Invoice": "1",
                "PO": "2",
                "Qty": "9",
                "Rev": "5",
                "Status": "11",
                "Total Sales": "13",
                "Unit Price": "10"
            },

            "B": {
                "Actual Sales": "14",
                "Code": "3",
                "Comment": "15",
                "Date Due": "8",
                "Date Received": "7",
                "Description": "6",
                "Drawing Number": "4",
                "Due Day": "12",
                "Invoice": "1",
                "PO": "2",
                "Qty": "9",
                "Rev": "5",
                "Status": "11",
                "Total Sales": "13",
                "Unit Price": "10"
            }
        }
        "Feb": {
            "A": {
                "Actual Sales": "14",
                "Code": "3",
                "Comment": "15",
                "Date Due": "8",
                "Date Received": "7",
                "Description": "6",
                "Drawing Number": "4",
                "Due Day": "12",
                "Invoice": "1",
                "PO": "2",
                "Qty": "9",
                "Rev": "5",
                "Status": "11",
                "Total Sales": "13",
                "Unit Price": "10"
            },

            "B": {
                "Actual Sales": "14",
                "Code": "3",
                "Comment": "15",
                "Date Due": "8",
                "Date Received": "7",
                "Description": "6",
                "Drawing Number": "4",
                "Due Day": "12",
                "Invoice": "1",
                "PO": "2",
                "Qty": "9",
                "Rev": "5",
                "Status": "11",
                "Total Sales": "13",
                "Unit Price": "10"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: wha is the expected output?

Comment: "How to read JSON file" — Depends on your JS environment and where you want to read the file from. "NodeJS / the local file system" and "A web page / a file input" and "A web page / a URL" will give different answers.

Comment: "and push it into array" — Try to limit yourself to a single question per question. Asking multiple questions at once is likely to get questions closed. (And are you really having problems figuring out how to push some data on to an array in JS? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+push&t=h_&ia=about )

Comment: "This JSON will goes on and on" — Why does that matter? If you want to push the whole thing onto an array, it doesn't matter how big it is (at least until you start running out of memory)

Comment: i read the file from firebase, the json i provide is the actual output from JSON.stringify() command except i cut out the 2016 above the 2017.

Comment: i want to read it like in the 2017 wrapper container​ then i can navigate to desired month and pull all the item inside A, B, C.. and display it in my browser. grouping them in the ”month” array would be preferable. really i have no idea what i m talking about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is unclear...

The JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format is mainly useful when you call APIs with Ajax. It is mostly an interchange format, just like XML. Here is an example with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            // Your JSON is here!
            var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log(this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
};

req.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com', true);
req.send(null);
```

Using a local JSON file is generally not the best solution because you will need to request asynchronously your filesystem. A better solution, especially if you use modules, is to go for a simple object literal to store information. With CommonJS, you could do something like this:

```
// data.js
module.exports = {
  foo: 'Foo',
  bar: 'Bar',
  baz: 'Baz'
};

// main.js
var data = require('./data');
```

Then, for whatever reason, you could push your data into an array using `Array.prototype.push()`:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(data);
```

---

**EDIT 1:** Your comment is still unclear, but... Do you want something like that?

```
var arr = [];

// Suppose your JSON is stored in a "json" variable
arr.push(json['Year']['2017']['Jan']['A']);
arr.push(json['Year']['2017']['Jan']['B']);
```

---

**EDIT 2:** Try this...

```js
var json = {
  "Year": {
    "2017": {
      "Jan": {
         "A": {
          "Actual Sales": "14",
          "Code": "3",
          "Comment": "15",
          "Date Due": "8",
          "Date Received": "7",
          "Description": "6",
          "Drawing Number": "4",
          "Due Day": "12",
          "Invoice": "1",
          "PO": "2",
          "Qty": "9",
          "Rev": "5",
          "Status": "11",
          "Total Sales": "13",
          "Unit Price": "10"
        },

        "B": {
          "Actual Sales": "14",
          "Code": "3",
          "Comment": "15",
          "Date Due": "8",
          "Date Received": "7",
          "Description": "6",
          "Drawing Number": "4",
          "Due Day": "12",
          "Invoice": "1",
          "PO": "2",
          "Qty": "9",
          "Rev": "5",
          "Status": "11",
          "Total Sales": "13",
          "Unit Price": "10"
        }
      },
      "Feb": {
        "A": {
          "Actual Sales": "14",
          "Code": "3",
          "Comment": "15",
          "Date Due": "8",
          "Date Received": "7",
          "Description": "6",
          "Drawing Number": "4",
          "Due Day": "12",
          "Invoice": "1",
          "PO": "2",
          "Qty": "9",
          "Rev": "5",
          "Status": "11",
          "Total Sales": "13",
          "Unit Price": "10"
        },

        "B": {
          "Actual Sales": "14",
          "Code": "3",
          "Comment": "15",
          "Date Due": "8",
          "Date Received": "7",
          "Description": "6",
          "Drawing Number": "4",
          "Due Day": "12",
          "Invoice": "1",
          "PO": "2",
          "Qty": "9",
          "Rev": "5",
          "Status": "11",
          "Total Sales": "13",
          "Unit Price": "10"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var arr = [];

for (var key in json['Year']['2017']['Jan']) {
  arr.push(json['Year']['2017']['Jan'][key]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: how do i navigate to year 2017 month of january and start pulling the object and push it into array?

Comment: @GsiX: I added a bit more information at the end of my answer. Please tell me if it is what you are trying to do...

Comment: when i first open my browser, first thing i need to do is to get all what ever data stored in my firebase. i converted the data into JSON as the example i show above for human readability. Then i would like to navigate into the specifict json object  let say year 2017, then navigate to desired month, then start pulling what ever child in there as shown A, B, C... store them in array so i can work with them later on. Thanks for your time.

Comment: my problem is i dont know how to navigate in the json object. let say i want to check if year 2017 exist, if yes i wan to check how many months there and try find the specific month. if it exists then i want to pull what ever data in there and push it into array.

Comment: OK. I added some code again in my answer. Please check it out. I think this is what you want. ;)

Comment: its like 1am here. i got to try it tomorrow and let you know. But as for now i would like to say that you nail it. all i have to do is loop thru each object and compare the string is not null. then go deeper check again until i found the specific object. If string compare is possible?

Comment: What you want is a simple loop. Check my "Edit 2" and try to play with it to suit your needs. By the way, have a good night! In France, it's 7 PM. :)

Comment: i just learned loop today so basically i have no picture of its usage until you show it. Thanks man and good night.

Answer (score -1):

```
[{
    "Year": 2017,
    "Jan": {
        "A": {
            "Actual Sales": "14",
            "Code": "3",
            "Comment": "15",
            "Date Due": "8",
            "Date Received": "7",
            "Description": "6",
            "Drawing Number": "4",
            "Due Day": "12",
            "Invoice": "1",
            "PO": "2",
            "Qty": "9",
            "Rev": "5",
            "Status": "11",
            "Total Sales": "13",
            "Unit Price": "10"
        },

        "B": {
            "Actual Sales": "14",
            "Code": "3",
            "Comment": "15",
            "Date Due": "8",
            "Date Received": "7",
            "Description": "6",
            "Drawing Number": "4",
            "Due Day": "12",
            "Invoice": "1",
            "PO": "2",
            "Qty": "9",
            "Rev": "5",
            "Status": "11",
            "Total Sales": "13",
            "Unit Price": "10"
        }
    },
    "Feb": {
        "A": {
            "Actual Sales": "14",
            "Code": "3",
            "Comment": "15",
            "Date Due": "8",
            "Date Received": "7",
            "Description": "6",
            "Drawing Number": "4",
            "Due Day": "12",
            "Invoice": "1",
            "PO": "2",
            "Qty": "9",
            "Rev": "5",
            "Status": "11",
            "Total Sales": "13",
            "Unit Price": "10"
        },

        "B": {
            "Actual Sales": "14",
            "Code": "3",
            "Comment": "15",
            "Date Due": "8",
            "Date Received": "7",
            "Description": "6",
            "Drawing Number": "4",
            "Due Day": "12",
            "Invoice": "1",
            "PO": "2",
            "Qty": "9",
            "Rev": "5",
            "Status": "11",
            "Total Sales": "13",
            "Unit Price": "10"
        }
    }
}]
```

This way you'll have a nice Json containing, for each position in the array, an information about the Year it's referring to ("Year" attribute), and for each month, you'll have a JSON object you can gather needed info from (A, B, ...)

Comment: well that 1 very helpful suggestions. i ll tweak something and see where it bring me. Thanks.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i doubt firebase will allow me to add same attribute name at the same level.

Comment: Of course it won't, but you can have something among the lines of

`[{
  "Year": 2017,
  "Jan": {...},
  "Feb": {...}
}, {
  "Year": 2018,
  "Jan": {...},
  "Feb": {...}
}]`